# Join 3 tables and databind to a ComboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Good morning SO.

I have 3 tables (Sql Server) with this layout:

```
   GenreMovies: | RowID | MovieGenre|
   GenreMusic:  |RowID | MusicGenre |
   GenrePodcast:| RowID | PodcastGenre|
```

I have a combobox/dropdown that I am trying to populate with a Query:

```
       var infoQuery =
                    (from MovieGen in dbContext.GenreMovies
                    select MovieGen.RowID)
                    .Union
                        (from MusicGen in dbContext.GenreMusics
                        select MusicGen.RowID).Union(from PodcastGen in dbContext.GenrePodcasts select PodcastGen.RowID).ToList();


        GridSortSearch.DataTextField = "MovieGenre";
        GridSortSearch.DataSource = infoQuery;
        GridSortSearch.DataBind();
```

I have two issues the query is only being populated with "RowID" 
and the combobox/dropdown is failing at the "DataTextField"

Comment: The query only comes with rowid because that is what you are selecting on each query, and because of that there is no field named "MovieGenre" that the combo can bind to. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I'm trying to have all the values from the columns be able to be selected in the dropdownlist. 

So all the values of MovieGenre column, ontop of MusicGenre column, on top of PodcastGenre column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said you need to return the same rows on results to achieve what you want.

Something like this, notice the change to the selects and the name of DataTextField value.

```
var infoQuery =
                    (from MovieGen in dbContext.GenreMovies
                    select new { MovieGen.RowID, Genre=MovieGen.MovieGenre})
                    .Union
                        (from MusicGen in dbContext.GenreMusics
                        select new {MusicGen.RowID, Genre=MusicGen.MusicGenre).Union(from PodcastGen in dbContext.GenrePodcasts select new {PodcastGen.RowID, Genre=PodcastGen.PodcastGenre).ToList();


        GridSortSearch.DataTextField = "Genre";
        GridSortSearch.DataSource = infoQuery;
        GridSortSearch.DataBind();
```

I couldn't compile/test this where I am at the moment but should work.

Comment: GREAT SCOTT! By jove! I believe we have gotten it! (requires further additional testing... hold please)...